# Objectify - fetching next and previous records

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm developing an application which is hosted on Google AppEngine. I'm using Objectify for the data operations. Consider an example Kind

```
Kind: Person
ID   Name
100  Santhosh
101  Upendar
102  Suresh
103  Naresh
```

I want to get the previous and next records while fetching the current records. For example, if I'm trying to get Person id 102, I would like to get 101 and 103 as well. I don't want to split these queries as that will have an impact on the number of data operations.

Is there a way/construct that can be used in this scenario.

Thanks

Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious solution would be to simply query for the other ids as well

```
ofy().load().type(Person.class).ids(101L, 102L, 103L);
```

If you want objectify to do this for you, you would need to change your Person class to be something like

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id Long id;
    // Other attributes here
    @Load Ref<Person> previousPerson; 
    @Load Ref<Person> nextPerson; 
}
```

But you would have to update the references if you insert or delete a new element. I doubt that this would be efficient using the datastore.

Comment: Hi JoSo - sorry, I was talking about the dynamic data. i.e.; I'll have 1000s of records like this. And when I fetch a particular ID, I want to get the previous and next id. Thanks for your suggestion. I want to avoid populating the next/previous id while inserting the data.

Comment: The solutions mentioned above are the only ones i can think of. Objectify is very close to the datastore low level API which simply cannot do what you are asking for. If your ids are continuous the first suggestion would work with fetchId-1, fetchId, fetchId+1, however you are right that this would hardly work with dynamic data.  Depending on your use case you could try to change your data model, so the back-references are not required anymore.